# Container not running, and won't stop

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I have a container that appears to be stuck.

In the status it currently shows that it is "Networking". However none of the ports work.

I also am unable to stop it. Just gives me an error...

Comment: you should open a ticket here http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport or provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens that a container is in *Networking* state for too long and it usually means that the networking is being created for your Container so that the public and private IPs for your Container can be accessed and routed to your instance. When a container gets stuck on Networking then it is typically a problem with the infrastructure rather than anything you have done. You can try to create a new container from the same image with *cf ic run* or *ice run*. Please consider that if you reached the maximum quota you could need to delete the stuck container or to release unbound IPs in order to create a new one. You can delete a container using:

> cf ic rm -f *[containerId]*

To get the container id you can run:

> cf ic ps -a

You can list all IPs (available or not) using:

> cf ic ip list -a

Then you can release an IP using:

> cf ic ip release [IPAddr]

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation and I was able to remove it via command line:

```
cf ic rm your_container_id
```

After couple of minutes it was removed. For some reason via web console didn't work but it worked by command line.

Comment: You can also run the command with the -f option to force the removal. For example: cf ic rm -f container_ID     The information is also documented at the following URL: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/containers/ts_containers_navref.html#ts_debug_mode